# Replace new line with space on all lines but those starting with 00:

Tags: sed

I have a vtt file (subtitles) like this one, and I want to replace new lines with spaces only on  lines not starting with `00:` and/or empty lines.

So this:

```
00:07:44,759 --> 00:07:49,072
Quando comincio a lavorare?
Subito.

00:07:49,199 --> 00:07:53,512
Prendi quella poltrona e portala
in laboratorio. Quella?

00:07:53,639 --> 00:07:58,839
Fai aftene'ione, mi raccomando.
lo vado in Comune. Arrivederci.

00:07:58,959 --> 00:08:01,952
Arrivederci.
Fate i bravi ragae'e'i.
```

will turn to this:

```
00:07:44,759 --> 00:07:49,072
Quando comincio a lavorare? Subito.

00:07:49,199 --> 00:07:53,512
Prendi quella poltrona e portala in laboratorio. Quella?

00:07:53,639 --> 00:07:58,839
Fai aftene'ione, mi raccomando. lo vado in Comune. Arrivederci.

00:07:58,959 --> 00:08:01,952
Arrivederci. Fate i bravi ragae'e'i.
```

In each block, there may be one or two lines of subtitles.

I tried `sed` to remove new lines while ignoring those that start with `00:` or containing `-->` but didn't find the way.

I think I can write a bash script to read the file line by line and act accordingly but I'm pretty sure `sed` can also do it on just one line.

Comment: Are the subtitle texts always two lines, or can they be also one or three?

Comment: can be one, not three.

Answer (score 3):

```
sed '/^$\|-->/!{
    N
    /\n$/!s/\n/ /
}' file
```

- `/^$\|-->/!` If line is neither empty nor contains `-->`;
- `N` append next line to pattern space.
- `/\n$/!s/\n/ /` If the line appended is not empty, substitute newline character by space.

Sample input (this contains a single line subtitle in 2nd block, as OP commented they can show up):

```
00:07:49,199 --> 00:07:53,512
Prendi quella poltrona e portala
in laboratorio. Quella?

00:07:58,959 --> 00:08:01,952
Arrivederci.

00:07:58,959 --> 00:08:01,952
Arrivederci.
ABC.
```

Output:

```
00:07:49,199 --> 00:07:53,512
Prendi quella poltrona e portala in laboratorio. Quella?

00:07:58,959 --> 00:08:01,952
Arrivederci.

00:07:58,959 --> 00:08:01,952
Arrivederci. ABC.
```

Note: As @binarysta commented, `-->` is more reliable than `00:` to detect the headers in case the video is more than one hour long. If you really want `00:`, you can change the first regex to `/^$\|^00:/`.

Comment: maybe better to search for `/^$\|-->/!` because if the content is more than 1 hour, this will not work.

Comment: I think this answer is correct for regular plain text files, but it looks like vtt files might not be regular "plain" text files or something. 

I tried with this file https://www.democracynow.org/resources/captions/shows/6356/English.vtt and it add some weird `^M` characters. 

I don't know if I'm breaking any rule by asking this too specific question. Am I?

Comment: The file was actually in `CRLF` format, so it needed to be transformed it to `LF`; I did it with `dos2unix` and the provided sed command worked as expected. Thanks!